# How to update column value with filename through SQL Loader Control File?

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, plsql, batch-processing

I need to read the file name to an column through a SQLLoader Control file. How can we do it?

control file as below.

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET UTF8
Apend
INTO TABLE XX_Update_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
(CUSTOMER_ID,
Customer_NAME,
FileName   ***<How to pass file name here>***
)
```

OS is Windows..

file name like :-

```
20171005_1_batch1.txt
```

Contents as below :

```
1.23456|ramanujan
1.56678|ravi
```

SQL-loader command:

```
sqlldr userid=system/123@instance1 control=D:\ControlFile\control_file.ctl data=D:\ControlFile\Data\20171005_1_batch1.txt
```

Please help.

Comment: Maybe this [guide](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1287968) can help you

Comment: I am doing in Windows. I cant use Unix script.

Comment: where does the filename comes from, will it be the same value for all rows you're loading?

Comment: Through sqlldr command data value.

Comment: so it comes from your data directly, then it's not a constant, why use a constant in this case?

Comment: of I am fine without defining it has constant. How do we get the value into this field?